# Валидация сертифика на WebLogic

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic

как реализовать проверку клиентского сертификата по ssl_client_s_dn_cn на weblogic?
можно ли это сделать через интерфейс админки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию WebLogic Server настроен на использование односторонней идентификации SSL (сервер передает свою идентификацию клиенту). Когда серверу требуется аутентифицировать клиента, используется двусторонняя идентификация по SSL(Two Way Client Cert Behavior).

При двустороннем соединении клиент проводит идентификацию сервера, а затем передает свой сертификат на сервер. Затем сервер проверяет сертификат идентификации клиента перед завершением подтверждения SSL. Настраивается через [админку](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/WLACH/taskhelp/security/ConfigureTwowaySSL.html).

> In the left pane of the Console, expand Environment and select
> Servers.
>
> Click the name of the server for which you want to configure
> SSL.
>
> Select Configuration > SSL, and click Advanced at the bottom of
> the page.
>
> Set the Two Way Client Cert Behavior attribute. The
> following options are available:
>
> ```
> Client Certs Not Requested: The default (meaning one-way SSL).
> Client Certs Requested But Not Enforced: Requires a client to present a certificate. If a certificate is not presented, the SSL connection continues.
> Client Certs Requested And Enforced: Requires a client to present a certificate. If a certificate is not presented, the SSL connection is terminated.
> ```
>
> Click Save.

Ваш вариант - Client Certs Requested And Enforced.

Comment: Спасибо, а скажите, это то же самое что и mutual SSL?
Т.е. нам нужно, чтобы наш сервер запросил клиентский сертификат и проверил его по DN

Comment: да, вот еще один похожий вопрос с отсылкой к документации по конфигурированию SSL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55322575/how-to-properly-perform-mutual-authentication-in-java-and-weblogic-12c

Comment: Вроде все сделали, как Вы писали и по инструкции из доки. https работает, а запроса сертификата в браузере не происходит.